# rename multiple files based on a another file

Tags: sed, mv

I have a folder with ~300 files

```
PD26414b.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
PD26414b.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.crai
PD26415g.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
PD26415g.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.crai
```

I want to replace the IDs (PD26414b,PD26415g) in the file names with their homolog names which I have saved in a text file

```
head names.homologs.txt
PD26414b SAMEA3471115
PD26415g SAMEA3471120
PD26433c SAMEA3471126
PD26429d SAMEA3471130
```

so the homolog names of PD26414b is SAMEA3471115.

My desired file names would be

```
SAMEA3471115.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
SAMEA3471115.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.crai
SAMEA3471120.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
SAMEA3471120.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.crai
```

Is there any way to do it in Linux
?
I know it should be a combination of sed and mv but do not know exactly the command

Comment: Are you really on Unix or do you mean Linux? If Unix, which one? If Linux, also which one?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Linux, that way a typo. I edited that

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux machine or otherwise have access to the perl rename command (this can be called `rename` or `prename` or `perl-rename` depending on the operating system), and assuming you can never have spaces or other whitespace in the ID, you can do:

```
while read id hom; do
    rename -n "s/^$id/$hom/" "$id".*
done < names.homologs.txt
```

That will just print what it will do but will not actually rename anything. Once you have checked that it does what you want, run it again without the `-n` option to actually make the changes.

---

Alternatively, you can also do this in the shell:

```
while read id hom; do
    for file in "$id".*; do
        newFile=$(printf '%s\n' "$file" | sed "s/$id/$hom/")
        mv -- "$file" "$newFile"
    done
done < names.homologs.txt
```

But note that this assumes that there will be no name collisions (if a file's new name corresponds to the name of an existing file, then the existing one will be over-written), no newlines in your file names (which really should be a safe assumption with cram files).

Comment: A very slight improvement might be ... `sed "s/^$id\./$hom./"`

Comment: The `while` loop is input starved.

Comment: The `for` loop is better written as `"$id".*`

Comment: @guest_7 good points both, thank you. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A pure `bash` solution, provided as @terdon says no weird characters in filenames, and not a huge number of homologs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a homologs

while read key val
do {
  homologs["$key"]="$val"
} done < names.homologs.txt


while read file
do
# key is the part before the dot
  key="${file%%.*}"
# end is part after the first dot to the end
  end="${file#*.}"
  printf 'mv -- "%s" "%s.%s"\n' "${file}" "${homologs["$key"]}" "$end"
done
```

Comment: There's no need to export the keys since the `whioe` loop operates in the current shell due to its input being redirected and not piped.

Comment: The second while loop is all dressed up and ready to go but doesn't get its input.

Answer (score 0):

In case the rename utility is not installed, we can always roll our own , but with no bells and whistles:

```
perl -le 'local $/;
  my %h = <STDIN> =~ /^(.*) (.*)$/mg;
  rename $_, s/^[^.]+/$h{$&}/r
    for @ARGV;
' *cram* < names.homologs.txt
```

With the homologs file on pearl's stdin' from where we initialize the name mapping hash and apply it in the subsequent rename command.

---

We can try doing it with sed as there are no newlines in filenames

```
sed -Ee '
  1i\
h
  s|\S+|s/^[.][/]&[.]/|
  s||.\\/&./;ta|2
$a\
:a\
G\
s/(.*)\\n(.*)/\\2 \\1/
' names.homologs.txt > genMvPairs

  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.cram*' |
  sed -Ef genMvPairs - | xargs -n2 -t mv -f
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be similar to the second half of [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645852/116858), but I'm using a safer and much quicker way of computing the new names of the files.

Using `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

while read -r id homolog; do
        for oldname in "$id".*; do
                [ -e "$oldname" ] || continue
                newname=$homolog.${oldname#$id.}
                mv -- "$oldname" "$newname"
        done
done <names.homologs.txt
```

This assumes that the file we want to rename are located in the current directory.  The script reads the two strings from each line of the `names.homologs.txt` file into the two variables `id` and `homolog`.

For each `id`, it tries to loop over the files whose names matches `"$id".*` in the current directory.  For each such file, if it exists at all, the name is modified by replacing the `$id.` part that we know is at the start of the string with `$homolog.`.  The `mv` utility is then used to actually rename the file.

No check is made for name collisions.